# Jupyter notebook & 'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: python, git, jupyter-notebook

I am trying the following code in a jupyter notebook

```
if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(paths['APIMODEL_PATH'], 'research', 'object_detection')):
    !git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/models {paths['APIMODEL_PATH']}
```

but I get the following error

'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Git seems to work fine in cmd.

I tried %%bash and %%cmd but that did not help.

Any suggestions?

many thanks!

Comment: Do you have `git` actually installed in the PATH? It's not part of Jupyter Notebook, so it's not guaranteed that just because you have Jupyter Notebook you'll always/automatically have `git`.

Comment: re: "in the PATH" -- compare `os.environ['PATH']` in Jupyter Notebook to `echo "$PATH"` in bash.

Comment: (Also, referencing `cmd` implies you're on Windows. That raises more questions: If your git install is in the WSU environment but your Jupyter install is a native Windows one, well, there's your problem).

Comment: I had added bin and cmd to the path

Comment: Regarding echo "$PATH"  i get the answer "$PATH"

Comment: Regarding  os.environ['PATH'] I get a lot of folders as output

Comment: Yes, I am on Windows, I installed git all default except "Adjusting your PATH environment" where I selected "Use Git from Windows Command Prompt" toggle.